# Url Rewriting with IIS6 and Php

Tags: php, url-rewriting, web-config, iis-6

I have two websites very similar on two servers : 1 using IIS6 and the other using IIS7

Both are in Php.

For the one with IIS7 I used a web.config with that syntax :

```
<configuration>
<system.webServer>  
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
           <rule name="Rule1">
               <match url="^Test?$"></match>
               <action type="Rewrite" url="/test.php"></action>
           </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

It works fine. But I can't do it with IIS6

Constraints :

- II6 can't be upgraded
- I wan't to keep a web.config method (with Xml) : Ionics Isapi use Htaccess
- Php

Are there any other methods?

Thanks !

Comment: A client of mine has just taken over a website that uses this system too. But the problem is their site is on IIS6 server also.  I can't even change the code as its compiled .NET code and the source code is not up-to-date.